# Java long numeric

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi I'm trying to find the solution of 300^121 or 726^85 or like this long numeric operations but at netbeans on the output screen I can't see bigger than 9223372036854775807 how can I do these operations ?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [java.lang.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class. It lets you deal with integers larger than Long.MAX_VALUE. You can do something like:

```
BigInteger huge = BigInteger.valueOf(300).pow(121);
System.out.println("300^121 = " + huge.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Its got nothing to do with netbeans really, but instead its the maximum value that you can represent with a long. A long is represented as a signed 64 bit number, which means it can go up to 2^63 - 1, which is 9223372036854775807. There is a constant for this in `java.lang.Long` called `MAX_VALUE`.

To represent bigger numbers, you'll need to use BigDecimal or BigInteger. You could try something like this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(300).pow(121));
```

And it should give you this.

```
539103089974329363123953948852881511919442688261355331920300000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```